# Counter example with compact open convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, homotopy-theory

I would like an (easy?) example (if any) of a topological space $X$, a metric space $Y$, a sequence of funcions $f_n:X\to Y$, and a function $f:X\to Y$  such that:

1) each $f_n$ is continuous

2) $f_n\to f$ with respect to the compact open topology

3) $f$ is not continuous.

In other words, I search for a counter example to the sentence "compact open limit of continuous functions is continuous", which, as far as I can tell, it is not always true.

Comment: If $X$ is also  a metric space there is no such example.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. The compact-open topology is defined on the set $C(X,Y)$ of all continuous maps $X \to Y$. Therefore 2) has no meaning for $f \notin C(X,Y)$. I vote to close your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost Compact-open topology is not defined only on continuous functions. You can define it on any space of functions between two topological spaces. The question makes perfect sense. Always remember, Wikipedia is not a reliable source.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy could you please give a reference?

Comment: I'm also interested in positive statements: which conditions can be put on X so that compact-open limits of continuous functions are continuous?

Comment: @user126154 If you ask for a proof when $X$ is a metric space then I can post an answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes please, this would be very helpful

Comment: @user126154 I have posted  a proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Have you seen my possible counter example? (there $X$ is metric and compact!) according to your comment, and also to Henno Brandsma answer, it should be incorrect. But I'm not able to find the gap in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to discuss the following example:

$X=\{0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4...\}$ is a compact metric space (or any converging sequence together with its limit).

$Y=\{0,1\}$. It is clearly metric.

Now set $f_n=\mathcal 1_{[0,1/n]}$ the restriction to $X$ of the characteristic function of $[0,1]$, and $f=1_{\{0\}}$ be the function that holds $1$ in $0$ and zero elsewhere.

$||f_n-f||_{\sup}=1$ because $f_n(1/n)=1$ and $f(1/n)=0$.

On the other hand, $f_n$ seems to me converging to $f$ in the compact-open topology. This would provide a counterexample becauuse $f_n$ are continuous and $f$ is not.

Proof that $f_n\to f$ in the compact-open topology:

1) Non trival open sets of $Y$ are $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$,

2) Compacta of $X$ are:

2.1) finite subsets, or

2.2)  sets of the form $K=\{x_n\}\cup\{0\}$ where $x_n\to 0$ in $X$.

Therefore the non-trivial open neighborhoods of $f$ in the compact open topology are of the form

$V=\{g: g(0)=1,g(x_1)=....=g(x_k)=0\}$ for some $x_1,\dots,x_k\in X$ different from zero or

$V=\{g: g(x_1)=....=g(x_k)=0\}$ for some $x_1,\dots,x_k\in X$ different from zero.

Given such an open sets $f_n\in V$ eventually on $n$, precisely from $n$ bigger than $\frac{1}{\min(x_1,...,x_k)}$

Comment: Imho the neighborhood $V$ has to be adjusted to $V=\{g: \ g(x_1)=g(x_k)=0\}$, as the condition $g(K)=1$ is not satisfied by $f$. Since $f(K)=Y$ for compacts of type 2.2, conditions involving such compacts are trivial.

Comment: @daw yu're right, I'll change it.

Comment: I build this example from a comment here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349913/compact-open-limit-of-continuous-functions-is-continuous/349994#349994, where I also posted another example using $sin(1/x)$ as a limit function.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a $k$-space (aka compactly generated), then $f$ is continuous on $X$ iff $f\restriction_K$ is continuous on $K$ for all compact subsets of $X$. And for compact domain $K$, the compact-open topology is generated by the sup-metric and it's well-known that there the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. So your positive result will hold on all $k$-spaces (which includes metric and first-countable spaces, locally compact Hausdorff spaces, as its most typical subclasses.)

I think $X$ in the co-countable topology (not compactly generated) can be used to build a counterexample.

Comment: You say that compact-open topolgy is generated by sup-metric on compact. May be this is the point I'm missing: In order to prove that the compact-open topolgy is the uniform convergence topolgy on compacta, people usually use the continuity of the limit function. See for instance that question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868950/convergence-in-compact-open-topology-implies-uniform-convergence-on-compacts?rq=1

Comment: If you know a proof that compact-open topology is the same as uniform convergence on compacta, without using the continuity of  the limit function, it would be very useful if you post a proof.

Comment: Have you seen my possible countre example? According to your answer it should be incorrect, but I'm not able to find the gap.