# Quibble with proofs of the compact-open topology being equivalent to the uniform convergence topology: what happens if $f(x)$ is an isolated point?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, uniform-convergence, uniform-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ a uniform space. I would like to understand the proof that, if one endows $Y^X$ with the compact-open topology, if $f_n\to f\in Y^X$ under this topology then $f_n\rightrightarrows f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $X$.

[It has been answered on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868950/convergence-in-compact-open-topology-implies-uniform-convergence-on-compacts) and [answered on the site Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/General_Topology/The_compact-open_topology), but I have the same issue with both proofs. In the MSE answer, the author writes:

> Instead, note that for every $x\in K$ there is an open neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $f(U_x)\subseteq B_{\epsilon/3}(f(x))$.

And Wikibooks' proof says:

> For each such entourage $[W_x]$ let $U_x$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ such that $f(U_x)\subseteq W_x(f(x))$

This assumes continuity of $f$ (which admittedly *is* listed in the given assumptions). However, in Royden's text, it is left as an exercise to show uniform convergence iff. convergence in compact-open topology (where $Y$ is a metric space) *with no mention of continuity*. The above claims do not in general hold for discontinuous $f$, so I ask: is Royden's claim wrong, or is there a more general proof that does not rely on the continuity property?

Comment: $Y^X$ is the space of continuous functions so $f_n \to f$ in that space implicitly assumes all $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Royden defines $Y^X$ as the set of all maps from $X\to Y$. Was this a typo?

Comment: Map=continuous function.

Comment: Oh! @HennoBrandsma I must have read a hundred texts involving the word "map" and that was never mentioned. Is this a topology-specific nomenclature? I'm certain I've seen map used for non-continuous functions before

Comment: If someone says map, then one almost always tacitly means the morphism in the category one is working in. (Here, one works in the category of topological spaces, so a map means continuous function.)

Comment: Thanks to you both for clarifying that; this is a very important point!

Comment: Based on another question you've asked I'm assuming you are using the fourth edition. It's interesting that the analogous exercise (p.193, Exr.8.b) in the third edition is differently worded (In general there are many omissions made from the third to the fourth). There, the compact-open topology is defined on the set of all functions, and the exercise is to show the equivalence of the subspace topology on the continuous functions and the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets.